# java/php connecting to the asterisk server

Tags: php, javascript

i would like to ask if it is possible to connect the php code/java script in the Asterisk server .... plz someone answer my question i really appreciate your answer... please help me...and give me some codes or step how to make it... thank in advance

Comment: What do you want to do when you connect?  Why do you want to connect?

Comment: Do you mean java or javascript? These are not the same!

Comment: have you looked for an asterisk php library?

Answer (score 1):

You can interface with AMI by using PHP: [AMI PHP Examples](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example%3a+PHP).  As far as some sample code, you can fire PHP script from jquery/javascript using an ajax call.  Here is a sample script I wrote to rick roll friends, just POST a 10 digit phone number to it and it calls the phone number and plays 'never gonna give you up'.  This PHP script also assumes that its hosted on the same server that your asterisk instance is hosted on, you can change the $strHost if it's not.

PHP Script:

```
#now some variables are assigned to connect to asterisk
$strHost = "127.0.0.1";
$strUser = "yourusername";
$strSecret = "yourpassword";
$strWaitTime = "30";
$strPriority = "1";
$strMaxRetry = "2";

#get the value from the form in rickroll.php
$strExten = $_POST['txtphonenumber'];

#some asterisk CLI debugging stuff
$callNumber = $strExten;
$strCallerId = "RICKROLL <$callNumber>";

#get the length of our input (giggity)
$length = strlen($strExten);

#check to make sure the input value is at least 10
#digits, if true, send the information to
#the "rickroll" context that is setup in extensions_custom.conf
  if ($length == 10 && is_numeric($strExten))
     {
        $oSocket = fsockopen($strHost, 5038, $errnum, $errdesc) or die("Connection to host       failed");
        fputs($oSocket, "Action: login\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Events: off\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Username: $strUser\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Secret: $strSecret\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Action: originate\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Channel: Local/1$callNumber@from-internal\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "WaitTime: $strWaitTime\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "CallerId: $strCallerId\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Exten: s\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Context: rickroll\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Priority: 1\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($oSocket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");
        sleep(3);
        fclose($oSocket);
     }

  //else tell them how to do it correctly
  else
     {
        echo ('Please enter a 10 digit number and try again');
     }
```

Then you'll need to add the something like the following to your extensions.conf to tell asterisk what to do with the call:

```
[rickroll]
exten => s,1,NoOp(inizio) ; verbose
exten => s,n,Answer
exten => s,n(message),Background(rickroll) ; "play rickroll.mp3 located in n/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/"
exten => s,n,WaitExten(5)
exten => t,1,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => t,2,Hangup
```

I hope that helps.